# OpenVPN 503 Service Unavailable behind http proxy

Tags: squid, openvpn

I have a OpenVPN server successfully setup on a digital ocean droplet following this amazing tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-18-04

Then I also made a http proxy server using squid proxy on a different droplet.

When I try to connect to my VPN server, I get 503 Service Unavailable on the logs of the client.
Also when I try to curl my VPN server, still the same result:

curl -I -x myproxy.com:80 http://myvpn.com:1194 or
curl -I -x myproxy.com:80 http://myvpn.com

I turned off the ufw of my OpenVPN server, still the same results.

Where should I fix?
My OpenVPN server? My My OpenVPN server's iptables? My squid proxy conf?

Please help..

Comment: I suggest you to move this question to the [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) site. It's more related to network and system administration.  

Though it's hard to understand where to fix the issue without configuration files provided, I guess the problem may be with the transport protocol used by OpenVPN. It often defaults to udp, but you need tcp in order your proxy to "see" the OpenVPN server. You can find more in the section "(Optional) Adjust the Port and Protocol" of that  tutorial from DigitalOcean.

Comment: Thankyou sir, yes my bad. I'm on my cellphone when I posted this. Will post in ServerFault in more detailed. Thankyou.

Comment: Discussioin on serverfault:

https://serverfault.com/questions/1037237/openvpn-503-behind-http-proxy

Comment: Issue is solve on: https://serverfault.com/questions/1037237/openvpn-503-behind-http-proxy Configs are also posted in the issue.